# Can headings in word have different colored numbering at the same level?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

Is it possible to have two headings at the same level, with two different styled numbering?

For instance;

1.2 heading 1 (1.2 in black)
1.3 heading 2 (1.3 in red)
1.4 heading 1 (1.4 in black)

Comment: What do you mean at same level?

Comment: well,
a heading with numbering like "1. Introduction" is level 1.
A heading with numbering like "1.1. Theory" is level 2. 
So two headings at the same level operates within the same place value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Of course, you can always customize the text in place.

First, select the whole line by clicking on the left margin:

[image: 1]

Then, choose the color:

[image: 2]

Now all the text is red! We need to change the text only back to black. Select the text from left to right, but move back a bit to exclude the "newline" character (?). Notice the difference with the one above:

[image: 3]

Now choose "Automatic":

[image: 4]

We're done!

[image: 5]

Comment: Yeah, i think i might have to go with the manual method, even though i have quite a lot of text.

Comment: Sure you can. See my edit of your post.

Comment: @Rune I rejected the edit (but the image can still be found [here](http://i.imgur.com/tmKz9Qv.png). I basically just missed that part, but still Word doesn't even have an odd/even styling rule, so I'm afraid that's it.

Comment: i dont want an odd/even styling rule. i want two different fonts. one with black numbering and one with red numbering at the same numbering level.

Comment: @Rune The conclusion is that, if you want different number style in the same list, you have to do it manually one by one.

Comment: @Rune you don't need to go manually. You should never use direct styling other than for bold, italic,... Those kind of approach don't work on big documents. I posted an answer that explain how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 versions, since not sure what you asking for.

Just select the text in heading and choose the color.

[image]

Comment: You are on the right track, but i need the text to be black.

Comment: You can chose any color you like for each heading.

Comment: i figured it out. i just, somehow, messed up my numbering fonts. i reset everything and it worked. my question is still on how to get black text and different colored numbering tho.

Comment: I am confused, Do you want the heading number to be in different color than the heading text ?

Comment: that is exactly what im saying

Answer (score 0):

A style separator would probably work for this. Use Control Alt Enter after the number and use a different style for tHe number and the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the style of any number or list, title automatic numbering is no different.

You can edit the numbering by modifying your style:
[image]

Or you can also use a direct style: Right click on the number of one of your title and select "Bullets and Numbering"

[image]

Then click on "Font..."

[image]

Their you can change the color or any other attribute. It will only apply to numbering and not on the title itself.

[image]